# Logging flying hours

Tags: arma-3

Is it possible to log the time I have spent flying aircraft?

I am starting to learn how to fly helicopters and I am interested in how much time I've spent in the air - or in the ground for that matter. Much like pilots do in the real-world.

Is there a mod, or perhaps a built-in character statistics somewhere?

Comment: If you want to keep it with realism in mind, why not write it down in a notebook? Real world pilots need to keep a logbook of how many hours they flew and other notes. Here's an example: [link](https://www.cumulus-soaring.com/books/ASA/logbook-pilot-hardcover-pg2-3.jpg)

Comment: Haha touchè. The problem with that is that real flights are probably an hour or more in duration, whereas I might fly for 30min here and 15min there. It would be a nightmare to record all of that each time I "get to da choppa".